# Getting errors when access one file using Kohana Framework

Tags: kohana-3.2

I use **Kohana v=3.2** and want to access check.php that located on webroot

```
webroot
  modules
  application
  system
  index.php
  check.php
  .htaccess
```

but when I access domain.com/check.php, I found

> HTTP_Exception_404 [ 404 ]: Unable to find a route to match the URI:
>   check.php

Can anyone help so I can access the file **domain.com/check.php** ?

Comment: Two hints: see the routing set up in bootstrap and the .htaccess file.

Comment: @MaGnetas : Could you help me the example, please

Comment: Well usually the .htaccess "lets through" the calls to physical files and folders. That's where might be the problem. On the other hand you might have set something in your application/bootstrap.php that is behaving this way. I guess quoting your .htaccess and bootstrap.php would help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the default .htaccess file (`example.htaccess`) that ships with Kohana.

```
# Turn on URL rewriting
RewriteEngine On

# Installation directory
RewriteBase /

# Protect hidden files from being viewed
<Files .*>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny From All
</Files>

# Protect application and system files from being viewed
RewriteRule ^(?:application|modules|system)\b.* index.php/$0 [L]

# Allow any files or directories that exist to be displayed directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT]
```

To enable your `check.php` file to be executed ensure that your .htaccess file contains the following lines at the bottom:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT]
```